# Unable to find the socket transport "https"

Tags: php, iis, fsockopen

I'm using this to check for the availability of a URL:

```
$fp = fsockopen($url, 443, $errno, $errstr);
```

and I get this error back...

**Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to https://example.com/soapserver.php:443 (Unable to find the socket transport "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?) in C:\Home etc etc....**

I'm using an IIS server btw,( no its not my doing! ) so I think its something to do with not having open-ssl, but I'm not sure. Can anyone help please?

I did a phpinfo() and I do have ssl, but on IMAP and cURL, thats all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

also for ssl you need to prefix the host with ssl://

Comment: This is the real answer, but tvanfosson clarified it :)

Comment: Full answer `$fp = fsockopen('ssl://'.$host, $prt , $errno , $errstr , 4) ;`

Answer (score 47):

Uncomment the line: `extension=php_openssl.dll` in `php.ini`

Comment: Do I need to do anything with php (sorry being a newbie on php) after I edited that file? Thank you.

Comment: Just realized this line is for Windows (dll), and it does not apply to Linux which I am using.

Answer (score 29):

You should be using just the hostname, not the URL in the fsockopen call.  You'll need to provide the uri, minus the host/port in the actual HTTP headers.  As @Martijin noted, and as listed in the manual page, you'll need to preface your host name with ssl:// for SSL or tls:// if using transport layer security.

[Manual page](https://www.php.net/fsockopen) for fsockopen.  Look at Example #1.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you wanted to grab NY Times, which enforces HTTPS:

Incorrect:

`$client = stream_socket_client('https://www.nytimes.com', $errno, $errstr, 30);`

Correct:

`$client = stream_socket_client('tcp://www.nytimes.com:443', $errno, $errstr, 30);`

Note I've replaced `https://` with `tcp://` and appended the 443 port to the hostname.

I guess we can say that `stream_socket_client()` does not speak URLs.

Comment: @Chris J Allen must've been desperate times

Answer (score 2):

Switching to `ssl://` worked for me but I kept getting a BAD REQUEST response. I found that I needed to add one more line to declare explicitly my Host Header as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27452744/paypal-sandbox-ipn-not-getting-verified-response/44076188#44076188) and ensure that I've updated my HTTP from `HTTP/1.0` to `HTTP/1.1`:

```
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check curl installed or not for php.
if it is not installed install the curl.
for windows Uncomment the line: extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini,
for ubuntu sudo apt-get install php-curl