# Paypal Sandbox IPN - Not getting VERIFIED response

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I hate asking a question which seems to have been asked many times before but from reading many posts I can't seem to figure out why I'm not getting the "VERIFIED" message back from paypal sandbox, I'm at this now several hours now and am not getting any further.

I email the result of the verify call to paypal, below is what it says, but no "VERIFIED", I'm testing using the IPN Simulator https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator

HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com
Server: BigIP
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");

    // Send an empty HTTP 200 OK response to acknowledge receipt of the notification
    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');

    // Assign payment notification values to local variables
    $item_name        = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number      = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status   = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount   = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $payer_email      = $_POST['payer_email'];

    // Build the required acknowledgement message out of the notification just received
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';               // Add 'cmd=_notify-validate' to beginning of the acknowledgement

    $msg = "";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {         // Loop through the notification NV pairs
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));  // Encode these values
        $req  .= "&$key=$value";                   // Add the NV pairs to the acknowledgement
    }

    $req = "";

    // Set up the acknowledgement request headers
    $header  = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";                    // HTTP POST request
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    // Open a socket for the acknowledgement request
    $fp = fsockopen ('www.sandbox.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    // Send the HTTP POST request back to PayPal for validation
    fputs($fp, $header . $req);

    $result = "";
    while (!feof($fp))
    {                     // While not EOF
        $res=fgets($fp, 1024);               // Get the acknowledgement response
        $result .= $res;

        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0){  // Response contains VERIFIED - process notification
            //db code here
        }
    }

    $to = 'test@email.com';
    $subject = 'Result';
    $m = $result;
    $headers = 'From: admin@email.com'."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: admin@email.com'."\r\n".
    'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $m, $headers);

    fclose($fp);  // Close the file
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a secure connection:

```
$fp = fsockopen ('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Matthew's response, I had to add an additional line to declare the HTTP Host as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810344/paypal-ipn-bad-request-400-error):

```
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
```

Also I wasn't able to get the https:// protocol to work on my server but switching it to ssl:// worked for me, reasoning detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378574/unable-to-find-the-socket-transport-https):

`$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);`

Answer (score -2):

I spent hours on this issue and it was none of the above (and elsewhere on web) but my code had an error in it elsewhere. It was a mix of code and I had not updated the sql connections even though they came after Paypal stuff. Essentially once I fixed the code it started to work. THe code was 'good' in that it worked elsewhere, but there were specific parts that did not, the sql connection and tables etc I cant quite remember what. But I would advise people experiencing this issue to remove all other code until they can check the Paypal IPN works. In my case I muddled through. I connect to a data base AND send phpmailer emails out so it was quite a long script in total, with things that would not work in the new environment. I guess this made the script fail even though I could see it by direct URL apparently working fine.