# PHP client Web socket to send messages

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, sockets, tcp

I have following code

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style type="text/css">

.panel{


margin-right: 3px;
}

.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 30%;   
    margin-left: 30%;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:30%;
    height:40px;
    margin-top: 5px;

}
input[type=text]{
        width:100%;
        margin-top:5px;

    }


.chat_wrapper {
    width: 70%;
    height:472px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background: #3B5998;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    padding: 10px;
    font: 14px 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
}
.chat_wrapper .message_box {
    background: #F7F7F7;
    height:350px;
        overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
}
.chat_wrapper  input{
    //padding: 2px 2px 2px 5px;
}
.system_msg{color: #BDBDBD;font-style: italic;}
.user_name{font-weight:bold;}
.user_message{color: #88B6E0;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */
    .chat_wrapper {
        width: 95%;
    height: 40%;
    }


    .button{ width:100%;
    margin-right:auto;   
    margin-left:auto;
    height:40px;}






}

</style>
</head>
<body>  
<?php 
$colours = array('007AFF','FF7000','FF7000','15E25F','CFC700','CFC700','CF1100','CF00BE','F00');
$user_colour = array_rand($colours);
?>


<script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
    //create a new WebSocket object.
    var wsUri = "ws://localhost:9000/demo/server.php";  
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 

    websocket.onopen = function(ev) { // connection is open 
        $('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">Connected!</div>"); //notify user
    }

    $('#send-btn').click(function(){ //use clicks message send button   
        var mymessage = $('#message').val(); //get message text
        var myname = $('#name').val(); //get user name

        if(myname == ""){ //empty name?
            alert("Enter your Name please!");
            return;
        }
        if(mymessage == ""){ //emtpy message?
            alert("Enter Some message Please!");
            return;
        }
        document.getElementById("name").style.visibility = "hidden";

        var objDiv = document.getElementById("message_box");
        objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
        //prepare json data
        var msg = {
        message: mymessage,
        name: myname,
        color : '<?php echo $colours[$user_colour]; ?>'
        };
        //convert and send data to server
        websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
    });

    //#### Message received from server?
    websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
        var msg = JSON.parse(ev.data); //PHP sends Json data
        var type = msg.type; //message type
        var umsg = msg.message; //message text
        var uname = msg.name; //user name
        var ucolor = msg.color; //color

        if(type == 'usermsg') 
        {
            $('#message_box').append("<div><span class=\"user_name\" style=\"color:#"+ucolor+"\">"+uname+"</span> : <span class=\"user_message\">"+umsg+"</span></div>");
        }
        if(type == 'system')
        {
            $('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">"+umsg+"</div>");
        }

        $('#message').val(''); //reset text

        var objDiv = document.getElementById("message_box");
        objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
    };

    websocket.onerror   = function(ev){$('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_error\">Error Occurred - "+ev.data+"</div>");}; 
    websocket.onclose   = function(ev){$('#message_box').append("<div class=\"system_msg\">Connection Closed</div>");}; 
});




</script>
<div class="chat_wrapper">
<div class="message_box" id="message_box"></div>
<div class="panel">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" maxlength="15" />

<input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" maxlength="80" 
onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13)document.getElementById('send-btn').click()"  />





</div>

<button id="send-btn" class=button>Send</button>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**server.php**

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost'; //host
$port = '9000'; //port
$null = NULL; //null var

//Create TCP/IP sream socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
//reuseable port
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

//bind socket to specified host
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);

//listen to port
socket_listen($socket);

//create & add listning socket to the list
$clients = array($socket);

//start endless loop, so that our script doesn't stop
while (true) {
    //manage multipal connections
    $changed = $clients;
    //returns the socket resources in $changed array
    socket_select($changed, $null, $null, 0, 10);

    //check for new socket
    if (in_array($socket, $changed)) {
        $socket_new = socket_accept($socket); //accpet new socket
        $clients[] = $socket_new; //add socket to client array

        $header = socket_read($socket_new, 1024); //read data sent by the socket
        perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port); //perform websocket handshake

        socket_getpeername($socket_new, $ip); //get ip address of connected socket
        $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' connected'))); //prepare json data
        send_message($response); //notify all users about new connection

        //make room for new socket
        $found_socket = array_search($socket, $changed);
        unset($changed[$found_socket]);
    }

    //loop through all connected sockets
    foreach ($changed as $changed_socket) { 

        //check for any incomming data
        while(socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1)
        {
            $received_text = unmask($buf); //unmask data
            $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text); //json decode 
            $user_name = $tst_msg->name; //sender name
            $user_message = $tst_msg->message; //message text
            $user_color = $tst_msg->color; //color

            //prepare data to be sent to client
            $response_text = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'usermsg', 'name'=>$user_name, 'message'=>$user_message, 'color'=>$user_color)));
            send_message($response_text); //send data
            break 2; //exist this loop
        }

        $buf = @socket_read($changed_socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
        if ($buf === false) { // check disconnected client
            // remove client for $clients array
            $found_socket = array_search($changed_socket, $clients);
            socket_getpeername($changed_socket, $ip);
            unset($clients[$found_socket]);

            //notify all users about disconnected connection
            $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' disconnected')));
            send_message($response);
        }
    }
}
// close the listening socket
socket_close($socket);

function send_message($msg)
{
    global $clients;
    foreach($clients as $changed_socket)
    {
        @socket_write($changed_socket,$msg,strlen($msg));
    }
    return true;
}


//Unmask incoming framed message
function unmask($text) {
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    }
    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    }
    else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    return $text;
}

//Encode message for transfer to client.
function mask($text)
{
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
    return $header.$text;
}

//handshake new client.
function perform_handshaking($receved_header,$client_conn, $host, $port)
{
    $headers = array();
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receved_header);
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $line = chop($line);
        if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
        {
            $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }

    $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
    $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
    //hand shaking header
    $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/demo/shout.php\r\n".
    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
    socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
}
```

The above code is working fine.But now i am looking for client side as php .can any provide me some example to make client websocket using php

**UPDATES**

I need to send byte array using php or javascript library through websocket

**Update 2**
I have found simple class of websocket but dont know how to use

https://github.com/paragi/PHP-websocket-client/blob/master/websocket_client.php

Also as per Niket Pathak answer i tried but getting following error

```
<?php
$host = 'ws://echo.websocket.org';  // your websocket server
$port = 80;
$local = "http://localhost";  // url where this script run | Client
$data = '{"id": 2,"command": "server_info"}';  // data to be sent

$head = "GET / HTTP/1.1"."\r\n".
        "Upgrade: WebSocket"."\r\n".
        "Connection: Upgrade"."\r\n".
        "Origin: $local"."\r\n".
        "Host: $host"."\r\n".
        "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13"."\r\n".
        "Sec-WebSocket-Key: asdasdaas76da7sd6asd6as7d"."\r\n".
        "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n"."\r\n";
// WebSocket handshake
$sock = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 2);
fwrite($sock, $head ) or die('error:'.$errno.':'.$errstr);
$headers = fread($sock, 2000);
fwrite($sock, hybi10Encode($data)) or die('error:'.$errno.':'.$errstr);
$wsdata = fread($sock, 2000);
fclose($sock);

var_dump(hybi10Decode($wsdata));

// hibi10 decoding of data
function hybi10Decode($data)
{
    $bytes = $data;
    $dataLength = '';
    $mask = '';
    $coded_data = '';
    $decodedData = '';
    $secondByte = sprintf('%08b', ord($bytes[1]));
    $masked = ($secondByte[0] == '1') ? true : false;
    $dataLength = ($masked === true) ? ord($bytes[1]) & 127 : ord($bytes[1]);
    if($masked === true)
    {
        if ($dataLength === 126) {
           $mask = substr($bytes, 4, 4);
           $coded_data = substr($bytes, 8);
        }
        elseif ($dataLength === 127) {
            $mask = substr($bytes, 10, 4);
            $coded_data = substr($bytes, 14);
        }
        else {
            $mask = substr($bytes, 2, 4);       
            $coded_data = substr($bytes, 6);        
        }   
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($coded_data); $i++) {       
            $decodedData .= $coded_data[$i] ^ $mask[$i % 4];
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($dataLength === 126) {          
           $decodedData = substr($bytes, 4);
        }
        elseif ($dataLength === 127) {           
            $decodedData = substr($bytes, 10);
        } 
        else {               
            $decodedData = substr($bytes, 2);       
        }       
    }   

    return $decodedData;
}

// hibi10 encoding of data
function hybi10Encode($payload, $type = 'text', $masked = true) {
    $frameHead = array();
    $frame = '';
    $payloadLength = strlen($payload);

    switch ($type) {
        case 'text':
            // first byte indicates FIN, Text-Frame (10000001):
            $frameHead[0] = 129;
            break;
        case 'close':
            // first byte indicates FIN, Close Frame(10001000):
            $frameHead[0] = 136;
            break;
        case 'ping':
            // first byte indicates FIN, Ping frame (10001001):
            $frameHead[0] = 137;
            break;
        case 'pong':
            // first byte indicates FIN, Pong frame (10001010):
            $frameHead[0] = 138;
            break;
     }

    // set mask and payload length (using 1, 3 or 9 bytes)
    if ($payloadLength > 65535) {
        $payloadLengthBin = str_split(sprintf('%064b', $payloadLength), 8);
        $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? 255 : 127;
        for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
            $frameHead[$i + 2] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[$i]);
        }

        // most significant bit MUST be 0 (close connection if frame too big)
        if ($frameHead[2] > 127) {
            $this->close(1004);
            return false;
        }
    } elseif ($payloadLength > 125) {
        $payloadLengthBin = str_split(sprintf('%016b', $payloadLength), 8);
        $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? 254 : 126;
        $frameHead[2] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[0]);
        $frameHead[3] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[1]);
    } else {
        $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? $payloadLength + 128 : $payloadLength;
    }

    // convert frame-head to string:
    foreach (array_keys($frameHead) as $i) {
        $frameHead[$i] = chr($frameHead[$i]);
    }
    if ($masked === true) {
        // generate a random mask:
        $mask = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
            $mask[$i] = chr(rand(0, 255));
        }
        $frameHead = array_merge($frameHead, $mask);
    }
    $frame = implode('', $frameHead);
    // append payload to frame:
    for ($i = 0; $i < $payloadLength; $i++) {
        $frame .= ($masked === true) ? $payload[$i] ^ $mask[$i % 4] : $payload[$i];
    }

    return $frame;
}
```

Error

> Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ws://echo.websocket.org:80
>   (Unable to find the socket transport "ws" - did you forget to enable
>   it when you configured PHP?) in G:\XAMPP\htdocs\a\server.php on line
>   16
>
> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   G:\XAMPP\htdocs\a\server.php on line 17 error:407024:Unable to find
>   the socket transport "ws" - did you forget to enable it when you
>   configured PHP?

Comment: Mostly because of the last paragraph, this seems too broad of a question. "_Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question._"

Comment: You can use Ratchet Websocket (http://socketo.me/), but again its a server-side implementation. I done something with CodeIgniter framework here. Please go through it. https://github.com/kishor10d/CodeIgniter-Ratchet-Websocket

Comment: @kishor10d.is it possible to send byte array

Comment: Try http://pieSocket.com  if you are looking for libaries to do it, they have PHP SDKs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are talking about connecting to your Websocket using Php, then **YES**, it is doable. There are a few libraries like [Php WebSocket client](https://github.com/gabrielbull/php-websocket-client) or [Websocket php](https://github.com/Textalk/websocket-php) that can connect to your websocket as a Client.

You can also check out this [Websocket Client](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6455.txt) for an example.

Another **Working Example** without using any library and implementing the  *hybi10 frame encoding* as per the [specification](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6455.txt):

```
$host = 'www.host.com';  // your websocket server
$port = 443;
$local = "http://localhost";  // url where this script runs | Client
$data = '{"id": 2,"command": "server_info"}';  // data to be sent

$head = "GET / HTTP/1.1"."\r\n".
        "Upgrade: WebSocket"."\r\n".
        "Connection: Upgrade"."\r\n".
        "Origin: $local"."\r\n".
        "Host: $host"."\r\n".
        "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13"."\r\n".
        "Sec-WebSocket-Key: asdasdaas76da7sd6asd6as7d"."\r\n".
        "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n"."\r\n";
// WebSocket handshake
$sock = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 2);
fwrite($sock, $head ) or die('error:'.$errno.':'.$errstr);
$headers = fread($sock, 2000);
fwrite($sock, hybi10Encode($data)) or die('error:'.$errno.':'.$errstr);
$wsdata = fread($sock, 2000);
fclose($sock);

var_dump(hybi10Decode($wsdata));

// hibi10 decoding of data
function hybi10Decode($data)
{
    $bytes = $data;
    $dataLength = '';
    $mask = '';
    $coded_data = '';
    $decodedData = '';
    $secondByte = sprintf('%08b', ord($bytes[1]));
    $masked = ($secondByte[0] == '1') ? true : false;
    $dataLength = ($masked === true) ? ord($bytes[1]) & 127 : ord($bytes[1]);
    if($masked === true)
    {
        if ($dataLength === 126) {
           $mask = substr($bytes, 4, 4);
           $coded_data = substr($bytes, 8);
        }
        elseif ($dataLength === 127) {
            $mask = substr($bytes, 10, 4);
            $coded_data = substr($bytes, 14);
        }
        else {
            $mask = substr($bytes, 2, 4);       
            $coded_data = substr($bytes, 6);        
        }   
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($coded_data); $i++) {       
            $decodedData .= $coded_data[$i] ^ $mask[$i % 4];
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($dataLength === 126) {          
           $decodedData = substr($bytes, 4);
        }
        elseif ($dataLength === 127) {           
            $decodedData = substr($bytes, 10);
        } 
        else {               
            $decodedData = substr($bytes, 2);       
        }       
    }   

    return $decodedData;
}

// hibi10 encoding of data
function hybi10Encode($payload, $type = 'text', $masked = true) {
    $frameHead = array();
    $frame = '';
    $payloadLength = strlen($payload);

    switch ($type) {
        case 'text':
            // first byte indicates FIN, Text-Frame (10000001):
            $frameHead[0] = 129;
            break;
        case 'close':
            // first byte indicates FIN, Close Frame(10001000):
            $frameHead[0] = 136;
            break;
        case 'ping':
            // first byte indicates FIN, Ping frame (10001001):
            $frameHead[0] = 137;
            break;
        case 'pong':
            // first byte indicates FIN, Pong frame (10001010):
            $frameHead[0] = 138;
            break;
     }

    // set mask and payload length (using 1, 3 or 9 bytes)
    if ($payloadLength > 65535) {
        $payloadLengthBin = str_split(sprintf('%064b', $payloadLength), 8);
        $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? 255 : 127;
        for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
            $frameHead[$i + 2] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[$i]);
        }

        // most significant bit MUST be 0 (close connection if frame too big)
        if ($frameHead[2] > 127) {
            $this->close(1004);
            return false;
        }
    } elseif ($payloadLength > 125) {
        $payloadLengthBin = str_split(sprintf('%016b', $payloadLength), 8);
        $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? 254 : 126;
        $frameHead[2] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[0]);
        $frameHead[3] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[1]);
    } else {
        $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? $payloadLength + 128 : $payloadLength;
    }

    // convert frame-head to string:
    foreach (array_keys($frameHead) as $i) {
        $frameHead[$i] = chr($frameHead[$i]);
    }
    if ($masked === true) {
        // generate a random mask:
        $mask = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
            $mask[$i] = chr(rand(0, 255));
        }
        $frameHead = array_merge($frameHead, $mask);
    }
    $frame = implode('', $frameHead);
    // append payload to frame:
    for ($i = 0; $i < $payloadLength; $i++) {
        $frame .= ($masked === true) ? $payload[$i] ^ $mask[$i % 4] : $payload[$i];
    }

    return $frame;
}
```

Lastly, you can send your byte data as a JSON object by encoding it to base64 first. 
Check this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706783/put-byte-array-to-json-and-vice-versa) to see how to do that. Hope this helps.

Comment: @niket.Thanks for the answer. but i need to send byte array only without encoding since c program code written like that

Comment: i ran your above code by changing host but getting error. 
Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ws://echo.websocket.org:80 (Unable to find the socket transport "ws" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?) in G:\XAMPP\htdocs\a\server.php on line 16

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in G:\XAMPP\htdocs\a\server.php on line 17
error:407024:Unable to find the socket transport "ws" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Comment: A [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378574/unable-to-find-the-socket-transport-https) as yours. Maybe you can try the solutions listed there. or perhaps use a library. I have updated my answer to include an easy-to-use library.

Comment: @Niket.thanks ya i already tried that but in that we send string only or else we have to send serialize data

Comment: @iCoders, you have used `$host = 'ws://echo.websocket.org';` as the host. You cannot use **`ws:`** for the handshake. Check documentation for [fsockopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) and [supported transport protocols](http://php.net/manual/en/transports.inet.php) needed for handshake.

Comment: @Niket.ya i agree ur point .my problem is i need to ws protocall but i can use it if i use external library thing is now i need ot send byte array

Comment: I think your "Websocket Client"  is pointing to the wrong link.

Comment: After a few days struggle finally found this thread and your answer works like a charm. All I had to add is a hybi10 encoding. Wishing you good health and happiness.

Answer (score 2):

My unswer NO. You can not fully use the websocket client logick, using only the server part(for example php). Because the server side know anything about the browser. Server - receives a request and returns a static result. All magic in the browser is javascript. Javascript can dynamically listen all user events, post a query to server and insert a response from the server to the page. Websocket can not work without javascript in browser.
This is WebSocket definition:

> WebSockets are a bi-directional, full-duplex, persistent connection
>   from a web browser to a server. Once a WebSocket connection is
>   established the connection stays open until the client or server
>   decides to close this connection. With this open connection, the
>   client or server can send a message at any given time to the other.
>   This makes web programming entirely event driven, not (just) user
>   initiated. It is stateful. As well, at this time, a single running
>   server application is aware of all connections, allowing you to
>   communicate with any number of open connections at any given time.

The only thing you can do, is learn node js. It will allow you to write the browser (client) part and server part on one language - javascript. But however this will be different parts of application, and you will use different approaches, to program each part

Comment: @Nutscracker.thanks for the answer.is there any php or javacript code to send byte array in wqebsocket.even library alos okay for me

Comment: @iCoders you can use javascript function ArrayBuffer https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays , https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data . Php have methods pack and unpack for binary data

Comment: @Nutscracker.Thanks can you provide me an simple example to send byte array using php packe and unpack.because i already try that .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43092252/php-send-array-bytes-in-web-socket

Comment: @iCoders And maybe this library will help you https://github.com/jDataView/jBinary.

Answer (score 0):

It's not what you want but could help. You can use Redis as a middleware. Use Redis publish/subscribe message system.
[Redis publish/subscribe message system](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub)